# U2F/FIDO forwarding over SSH

Tags: ssh, sshd, fido-u2f

Is there any mechanism to forward access to a U2F/FIDO security key (such as a Yubikey) over SSH? I'd like to be able to use my local security key to authorize sudo access on a remote host.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't native support for this in SSH, but there are some possibilities.

If you can cause the security key to be read over a Unix socket, you can forward a Unix socket over SSH in recent versions.  That, of course, depends on what tooling you're using to read it.

Alternately, if you're using the latest OpenSSH (8.2), there's built-in support for FIDO security keys, and the SSH agent should know how to handle them.  If you use Debian's libpam-ssh-agent-auth on the server, then you can authenticate with your FIDO2 ssh key via your forwarded agent.

Comment: Turns out that currently (Nov 2021) the solution with libpam-ssh-agent-auth does work, however, not with ecdsa-sk or ed25519-sk key types as they are not recognized by libpam-ssh-agent-auth. So you can use FIDO for ssh login, but then would have to fallback to another ssh key type for sudo auth.

Comment: Running into the same issue. Just wondering what other options do we have apart from password for sudo on a server where we don't have physical access